WinForms - Revert automatic resizing of form opened on a computer with 1440p monitor
While trying to deploy a new version of a WinForms application written in VB.NET, I noticed that all forms in the application have been resized and are now too large to be used on a Full HD monitor. Unfortunately, it seems like Visual Studio / the designer has automatically modified the .Designer.cs and also the .resx files when the project was opened on a computer with a 1440p monitor. For example, many controls are now larger than before and the ClientSize of the main form has changed from System.Drawing.Size(1558, 796) to System.Drawing.Size(2337, 1194)
Many changes have been implemented in the project since this happened, because the developer did not realize that the project was automatically modified in the background. Therefore, it is not trivial to revert those changes anymore.
Is there any simple solution to "re-scale" the project back to what it was before this change, or do we now have to manually revert this change for every single form and control?

While this does not apply to your current project, it could be interesting for your future projects (starting with .NET 8.0): Fix HDPI/scaling issues with Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio. Since .NET Framework 4.7 there is: Opting out of individual high DPI features.

I didn't test it: What happens if you delete the resx file?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes An exception is thrown at runtime if the resx file does not exist. This does not solve the problem.

https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/designer/designer-high-dpi-mode.md

Open the project on the computer with the original display settings (Full HD), and Visual Studio might adapt the forms back.
Then set AutoScaleMode to None or set a Consistent DPI Awareness for the Application.
